# SwiftUI Get object to respond to size of another object

Tags: swiftui

[image]

I'm designing a music player, and moving over from a storyboard interface to SwiftUI. I want the time to be displayed as a progress bar (that white line) that goes along the bottom edge of the track artwork. On large size canvases they are in line as they both are allowed to stretch out minus a padding of 20 on either side. However with smaller canvases the below issue happens. The artwork is made smaller to fit all the other views in, while the progress bar (a rectangle with height 2) remains larger. How can I set that rectangle so that if my artwork is made smaller the bar also gets smaller?

Here's my code:

```
struct PlayerArtwork: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                        Image("Pumpy Artwork")
                                .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        ProgressBar()
            }
            .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 20.0)
            HStack {
                Text("0:00")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Spacer()
                Text("3:52")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 20.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray)
            .frame(height: 2)

            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(height: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach using `alignmentGuide`. The idea is to update width of one view, in your case `ProgressBar` by the width fetched from dimensions available for alignment guide.

Note: probably you should made the same for time labels, but this is up to you

```
struct PlayerArtwork: View {
    @State private var boundWidth: CGFloat = 10.0 // any initial value
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Image("Pumpy Artwork")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .alignmentGuide(.bottom, computeValue: { d in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.boundWidth = d.width // avoid change state during update
                        }
                        return d[.bottom]
                    })
                ProgressBar()
                    .frame(width: self.boundWidth)
            }
            .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 20.0)
            HStack {
                Text("0:00")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Spacer()
                Text("3:52")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 20.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The alignment guide as per your code above still doesn't seem to react to the artwork image. With the new code, the progress bar is just set at what we initially set the boundwidth at (in this case 10)

Comment: It works here. Tested in Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2. The only of corse difference is that I used my images. How do you change image?

Comment: You're right, its does! It clicked into gear after a clean build...